# stdint.h: no such file or directory

Tags: compiling, make, gcc, benchmark

I am trying to compile coremarks to benchmark one of my CPU cores I generated (from here: https://gitlab.com/incoresemi/core-generators/benchmarks/-/tree/master).

I get the following error:

```
In file included from common/syscalls.c:3:
/usr/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/10.2.0/include/stdint.h:9:16: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
    9 | # include_next <stdint.h>
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:58: coremarks] Error 1
```

I already have the riscv toolchain installed. I also tried installing `libc6-dev` and `avr-libc` as I read this in a few answers online.

How do I resolve this?

thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to fix this error is: restrict gcc in using `stdint-gcc.h`

This can be done by adding c compiler flag

> -ffreestanding

to gcc

For more info on what is freestanding visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17692428)
and implied `-fno-builtin` visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18711719)